# Link to Native App in Facebook Post made with requestWithGraphPath is not Valid

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, facebook-timeline

I have a native iOS application that makes posts on the users timeline using:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

When the post shows on Facebook, it has the post info "XYZ minutes ago via MY_APP_NAME_HERE" where MY_APP_NAME_HERE is a link.  When I click on the link, then I am directed to a page http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=my_app_id that says "Page Not Found".

I have submitted an App Detail Page to the Facebook App Center, but that is at http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my_app_namespace?preview=1&locale=en_US.

How do I get this `MY_APP_NAME_HERE` link to work on my Facebook wall posts?  Do I have control over it in Xcode (I'm guessing no)?  Where is this link supposed to go... to my App Detail Page in the Facebook app center?  Am I not seeing it because my detail page isn't approved by Facebook yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to direct the link back to your iOS app you can control this in your Facebook App Dashboard:

Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
Then your app, Edit Settings and turn on:
- Configured for iOS SSO
- iOS Native Deep Linking

For more information on linking options see:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This is my first question - I tried to vote this answer up, but I guess I need 15 reputation points to do it.  Hopefully it will get voted up by others.  Thanks again!